# Getting error [setup.cfg] license_file parameter is deprecated while building docker image using jenkin/inbound agent alpine image

Tags: python, dockerfile, aws-cli, python-packaging

Getting error [setup.cfg] license_file parameter is deprecated while building docker image using jenkin/inbound agent alpine image.
I tried to change docker engine version and also tried with changing awscli,boto3 and botocore version too but didnt resolve this error.

using this code:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
   docker=${DOCKER_PACKAGE_VERSION} \
   python3 \
   py-pip \
   libc-dev \
   gcc \
   python3-dev \
   cmd:pip3 \
   musl-dev && \
 pip3 install pip --upgrade && \
 pip3 install -U \
        'aws-sam-cli>=1.20' \
        'boto3>=1.14.0' \
        'botocore>=1.18.63' \
        'awscli>=1.19.10' \
        'aws-lambda-builders>=1.2.0' \
        'cfn-lint>=0.47' \
        'docker-compose>=1.25.5' \
        --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge --no-cache del \
        gcc \
        python3-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libc-dev
```

```
Error :
Downloading aws_sam_cli-1.92.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting PyYAML==5.*,>=5.4.1 (from aws-sam-cli>=1.60)
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 175.1/175.1 kB 6.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
      
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1233, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 319, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 327, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 549, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 587, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-lu3huh4t/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried with change in version of boto3 and botocore version